# Errors prevented startup: While processing files with static-html

Tags: meteor

**Errors prevented startup: While processing files with static-html**

As my introduction to meteor I am testing forked package [Houston](https://github.com/gterrono/houston).
I ran the following commands.

```
$ mkdir tempspace
$ cd tempspace
$ git clone https://github.com/gterrono/houston
$ meteor create --bare houston
$ cd houston
$ meteor node -v
v4.8.4
# meteor reset  # starts from scratch, deletes databases
$ meteor update
This project is already at Meteor 1.5.2, the latest release.

Changes to your project's package version selections from updating package
versions:

dynamic-import  upgraded from 0.1.1 to 0.1.3

$ meteor run --port 192.168.1.98:3000
Selecting package versions
=> Started proxy
| Bulding for web.browser
| Linking
| Building for os.linux_x32
```

The first error message

```
=> Errors prevented startup:

While processing files with static-html (for target web.browser):
client/partials/admin_nav.html:1: Expected <head> or <body> tag
client/partials/custom_actions.html:1: Expected <head> or <body> tag
client/partials/flash_message.html:1: Expected <head> or <body> tag
client/third-party/bootstrap.html:1: Expected <head> or <body> tag
client/third-party/collapse.js.html:1: Expected <head> or <body> tag
test/test_app/my_tmpl.html:1: Expected <head> or <body> tag
test/test_app/test.html:11: Expected <head> or <body> tag
client/admin_change_password.html:1: Expected <head> or <body> tag
client/admin_login.html:1: Expected <head> or <body> tag
client/collection_view.html:1: Expected <head> or <body> tag
client/custom_template_view.html:1: Expected <head> or <body> tag
client/db_view.html:1: Expected <head> or <body> tag
client/document_view.html:1: Expected <head> or <body> tag
client/master_layout.html:10: Expected <head> or <body> tag
client/style.css.html:1: Expected <head> or <body> tag

=> Your application has errors. Waiting for file change.
=> Started MongoDB.
```

Development Version Info:

```
$ uname -a
Linux localhost.localdomain 3.6.10-4.fc18.i686.PAE #1 SMP Tue Dec 11 18:15:08 UTC 2012 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
$ meteor node -v  
v4.8.4
$ meteor --version 
Meteor 1.5.2
# by inspection
Houston 2.0.7
```

So I searched the web for similar questions and found:

- github dot com iron-meteor/iron-cli issue [#256], no answers to this issue yet ...

Taking the error message at face value, I added  a `<head>` and `<body>` tag
to the top of the file `client/master_layout.html` which did not change
the error message.

```
<head>
  <title>Houston</title>
</head>

<body>
    {{> _houston_master_layout}}
</body>

<template name="_houston_master_layout">
...
```

I did *not* see a similar issue in the original authors github issues, which makes me think maybe I have version problems, or I have installed something incorrectly.

As a sanity check, in a separate directory I installed a simple example from github leveluptuts/Blaze-Base to confirm the current meteor install was working okay. `OK`

---

**UPDATE** 20-Sept 2017

I was hoping to find a quick answer to this question by someone who has been down this path already.  So far no one has stepped up with an answer, so I am continuing my search and here is what I have found.

In .meteor/package

```
#static-html            # remove this package
blaze-html-templates    # add this package
```

**Resolves** the head tag not found error, but leads to other different errors, which I will take as a next debugging clue.

Comment: Could you add all steps to reproduce this error?

Comment: @Styx I have updated my original post to show exact commands to duplicate problem (on current dev machine).

Answer (score 11):

Same issue when reinstalling fresh meteor ... due to disk crash

```
meteor remove static-html
meteor add blaze-html-templates
```

Made my app able to start

Comment: Confirmed. Thank you.

Comment: but then i get 'Cannot read properties of undefined' err

Answer (score 1):

Yes, somewhat similar to my case. Meteor 1.5.2.2
I created a --bare project then add standard folders like client,server and public with the basic files in the client folder.

It works after commenting the static-html in .meteor/packages, then add blaze-html-templates

#static-html            # remove this package
blaze-html-templates    # add this package