# TypeError: Package.describe is not a function at meteorInstall.package.js

Tags: meteor

In an example **Meteor** project

- While trying to understand how `package.js` works I copied the simple-todos example from the meteor blaze tutorial.

  `mkdir tempspace
  cd tempspace; meteor create simple-todos
  cd simple-todos; meteor`
- Then I created the file `package.js` in the simple-todos  directory, and added the following content:

`Package.describe({
        name: "demo:todos",
        summary: "A zero-config todo",
        version: "0.0.1",
        git: "not available"
     });`

and then received this error in the terminal:

`W20170920-13:59:43.473(-7)? (STDERR) /home/myname/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.5.2.1q1fcxy++os.linux.x86_32+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_32/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:280
W20170920-13:59:43.491(-7)? (STDERR)                        throw(ex);
W20170920-13:59:43.496(-7)? (STDERR)                        ^
W20170920-13:59:43.501(-7)? (STDERR) 
W20170920-13:59:43.504(-7)? (STDERR) TypeError: Package.describe is not a function
W20170920-13:59:43.506(-7)? (STDERR)     at meteorInstall.package.js (package.js:1:9)`

- This makes me think there is an import problem, as the compiler seems to not know about `Package.describe`.
- This of course is a mock problem...  The real problem is with a published package that has the same problems with package.js on my development environment.  I just figured I would simplify the troubleshooting and try a known good app.

---

Edit: 21-Sept 2017

Following @Mikkel's advice:

`$ meteor --version
    Meteor 1.5.2
    $ git clone https://github.com/mikkelking/meteor-presence.git
    $ meteor create --bare meteor-presence/
    $ cd meteor-presence/
    $ meteor`

returns exactly the same error message:

```
"/home/myname/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.5.2.1q1fcxy++os.linux.x86_32+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_32/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:280"
"TypeError: Package.describe is not a function"
```

Every 'known good' project that I download has the same problem.  The clue appears to be in the first line of the error message.  Something is not being passed correctly to the 1.5.2 version of future.js. Hmmm.

---

Did I miss something in the api doc about how to add package.js?

Comment: How did you install the published package, npm?

Comment: See so [46272137](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46272137/errors-prevented-startup-while-processing-files-with-static-html)

Answer (score 0):

`package.js` is used to describe a package, not an app, so you shouldn't put this file in the root of the project.

If you want an example, you can clone this repo: https://github.com/mikkelking/meteor-presence

It's a very simple package, and you can see how package.js is used to describe the parts and functions of the package

Comment: I followed your clone recommendation and posted the results in my original post.  Testing a known good project yields the same error, which means it is not the project causing the error, but perhaps my install of meteor 1.5.2 .  Maybe I need to remove it and and start over.